# Fizzbuzz using shapes (p5.js)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement, processing, p5.js

I am currently trying to create a fizzbuzz using shapes but cannot get the divisible by 3 and 5 square to show up correctly. Ive searched for answers but no one seems to have tried this.

**Write a program that draws 25 black circles to the screen, oriented horizontally. Please accomplish this with a for loop that starts at zero, and increments an iterand forward by one each iteration.**

However,

**When the iterand is divisible by 3, draw a purple circle instead 
When the iterand is divisible by 5, draw a green square instead 
When the iterand is divisible by 3 AND 5, draw a blue square instead**

```
function setup() {
createCanvas(1500, 1500);
ellipseMode(CENTER);
}

function draw() {
  background(200);
  var y = 100;
  // 25 black squares
  for (let x = 0; x < 1250; x += 50) {
    fill(0);
    ellipse(x, y, 50, 50);
    // sets the purple circle
    if (x % 3 === 0) {
      fill(153, 31, 240);
      ellipse(x, y, 50, 50);
    }
    // sets the green squares should be on top
    if (x % 5 === 0) {
      fill(0, 255, 0);
      square(x + 25, y - 25, 50);
    }
    // sets the last blue square
    // issue is the is supposed to be only one at the 15 mark
    if (x % 3 == 0 && x % 5 == 0) {
      fill(0, 0, 255);
      square(x + 25, y - 25, 50);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The major issue, is that your conditions evaluate `x`. Note, `x` is the x coordinate and a multiple of 50.
You have to evaluate the index of the field.

Read your own instructions carefully:

> [...] accomplish this with a for loop that **starts at zero**, and increments an **iterand forward by one** each iteration.

Furthermore the shapes have to be draw **"instead"**.

Run a loop from `i=0` to `i<25`:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 25; ++ i)
```

and use a

```
if () { ... } else if () { ... } else { ... }
```

sequence:

See the example:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(1500, 1500);
}

function draw() {
    background(200);
    var y = 100;
    // 25 black squares
    for (let i = 0; i < 25; ++ i) {
        let x = i*50; 
        
        if (i % 3 == 0 && i % 5 == 0) {
            // sets the last blue square
            fill(0, 0, 255);
            square(x, y, 50);
        }
        else if (i % 5 === 0) {
            // sets the green squares should be on top
            fill(0, 255, 0);
            square(x, y, 50);
        }
        else if (i % 3 === 0) {
            // sets the purple circle
            fill(153, 31, 240);
            ellipse(x+25, y+25, 50, 50);
        }
        else {
            // black circle
            fill(0);
            ellipse(x+25, y+25, 50, 50);
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.10.2/p5.js"></script>
```